# What is the difference between endometrial lining and endometrial stroma?

Tags: embryology

This is in the context of embryology whereby the syncytiotrophoblast erodes the endometrial stroma during the penetration and implantation of the zygote.

But I don't know the correct terminology of what exactly has been eroded.